# what is the difference between ? and T in class and method signatures?

Tags: java, generics

why does

```
public interface ArrayOfONEITEMInterface <T extends ONEITEMInterface>{
    public List<T> getONEITEM();
}
```

compile, but not

```
public interface ArrayOfONEITEMInterface <? extends ONEITEMInterface>{
    public List<?> getONEITEM();
}
```

what is the difference between ? and T in class and method signatures?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`?` is a wildcard and means **any** subclass of `ONEITEMInterface` including itself.

`T` is a **specific** implementation of `ONEITEMInterface` in this case.

Since `?` is a wildcard, there is no relation between your `?` in the class declaration and the `?` in your method declaration hence it won't compile. Just `List<?> getONEITEM();` will compile though.

---

The **first scenario**  means the entire class can handle exactly **one** type of `Bar` per *instance*.

```
interface Foo<T extends Bar> {
     List<T> get();
}
```

The **second scenario** allows *each instance* to operate on **any** subtype of `Bar`

```
interface Foo {
     List<? extends Bar> get()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

T is a placeholder for a type that will be provided by an implementing or instantiating class.

? is a placeholder saying "I don't know or care what the generic type is" generally used when the work you'll do on the container object doesn't need to know the type.

The reason you can't use '?' in the class/interface definition is because there's the value is saying defining the name of the placeholder (and the type will be provided elsewhere). Putting a '?' doesn't make sense.

Furthermore, the placeholder doesn't need to be T, it can any standard Java variable. By convention, it is one capital character, but need not be.

Answer (score 5):

? allows you to have a list of Unknown types, where as T requires a definite type.

Answer (score 4):

The clause `<T extends ONEITEMInterface>` is declaring a type parameter named `T`. This allows your generic type, `ArrayOfONEITEMInterface`, to refer to the parameter elsewhere. For example you can declare a method like `void add(T t)`.

Without naming the type parameter, how would you refer to it? If you never refer to the type parameter, why is your type generic in the first place? For example, you don't need a parameterized type to do something like this:

```
public interface ArrayOfONEITEMInterface {
    List<? extends ONEITEMInterface> getONEITEM();
}
```

It doesn't make sense to declare an anonymous type parameter, so it is syntactically illegal.

Comment: `Without naming the type parameter, how would you refer to it? If you never refer to the type parameter, why is your type generic in the first place?` So, ? in class declaration and ? in return type of the method are no way related to each other so it doesn't make sense to have ? in the class declaration. Does that imply that ? in class declaration will always be a compile-time error?

Comment: @ajaysinghnegi It's illegal in the position where [a type identifier is required](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) (the first token of a type parameter on a class declaration), but `?` can appear in the type bounds for that identifier. So, in `class Sample<T extends Comparable<?>>`, what appears as `T` has to be a valid Java identifier, which excludes `?`, but the `?` in the bounds `extends Comparable<?>` is valid. And, yes, you're right that the `?` in the class declaration and the `?` in the method's return type would be unrelated (if that were legal).