# How to get use GSON.fromJson with type provided in a variable?

Tags: java, generics, gson

I wanted to use GSON.fromJSON in the following way:

```
Class<?> type = Abc.class;
Class<?> parametersObject = GSON.fromJson(parameters, type);
```

But I am getting compilation error on 2nd line. How do I infer the return type of the following line? I know it would be of Abc type in the above case. But I want to make this dynamic based on what is specified in type variable. How can I do that?

Comment: can you show un an example?

Comment: Posted a more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071516/how-to-make-the-java-code-generic-for-handling-different-kind-of-pojos-and-addin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the below code. There is a question about the difference between `?` and `T` in class and method signatures, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573269/what-is-the-difference-between-and-t-in-class-and-method-signatures).

```
public class Tests<T> {

    @Test
    public void test01() {
        Tests<String> stringTest= new Tests<>();
        System.out.println(stringTest.parseObject("testtestt", String.class));
    }

    public T parseObject(String parameters, Class<T> clazz) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        T obj = (T) gson.fromJson(parameters, clazz);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

``
**UPD:**
 declare `<T> T` returning type of method.

```
@Test
public void test02() {
    String stringstring = parseObject02("stringstring", String.class);
    System.out.println(stringstring);
    List list = parseObject02("[1,2,3]", List.class);
    System.out.println(list);
//        output in console
//        stringstring
//        [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
}

public <T> T parseObject02(String parameters, Class<T> clazz) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    T obj = gson.fromJson(parameters, clazz);
    return obj;
}
```